# In Alamofire, SessionManager.swift, I don't know this code meaning: delegate[task] = request

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am reading the source code of Alamofire, in this class SessionManager.swift, I don't know what is this code meaning : delegate[task] = request. in object,object can have [] operate? or is the delegate is a dictionary? oh,that seems impossible，so I don't konw the use of this code, can anyone help me? thanks very much

```
    open func request(_ urlRequest: URLRequestConvertible) -> DataRequest {
    var originalRequest: URLRequest?

    do {
        originalRequest = try urlRequest.asURLRequest()
        let originalTask = DataRequest.Requestable(urlRequest: originalRequest!)

        let task = try originalTask.task(session: session, adapter: adapter, queue: queue)
        let request = DataRequest(session: session, requestTask: .data(originalTask, task))

        delegate[task] = request

        if startRequestsImmediately {
            request.resume()
        }

        return request
    } catch {
        return request(originalRequest, failedWith: error)
    }
}
```